# Problem mounting a cdrom

Tags: mount, 15.10, cd-drive

I am baffled by CDs under Ubuntu 15.10.
When I insert an audio CD in the drive, it is recognized as such and can be played (Rhythmbox for instance). An icon appears on the desktop.
When I insert a DVD (either with text, photos or movie), it recognized and can be opened or played (VLC). An icon is again displayed.
When I insert a data CD, nothing much happens. I tested about 20 different CDs and, surprise, two of them were recognized and opened (?); they are older than the others (burned in 2000-2005 I guess).

First question: What is the reason for this strange behavior? A CD is not such an outlandish device and successive versions of Windows don't seem to be harmed by them.

I can insert a line in fstab connecting /dev/sr0 to some mounting point

```
/dev/sr0   /media/cdrom   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0
```

CDs are automatically recognized then. This raises further questions.

Which folder/file should I choose: cdrom, mnt, media ? All are at first empty.

I have several user accounts on this machine: how can they all access /media/cdrom ?

Finally, when I click on eject, Ubuntu asks for my administrator password; how can I prevent that?

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Is your system up-to-date? (`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`)  Have you tried updating the BIOS/UEFI?  Are there any firmware updates available for your CD drive, and if so, have you installed them?  ([Imgburn](http://www.imgburn.com/) can check for firmware updates, install it using Wine.  (See http://askubuntu.com/questions/729375/running-steam-through-wine/729377#729377 for installation instructions.))