# Wine Not Able To Run .exe File(s)

Tags: windows, wine, executable

Before I installed Ubuntu on my laptop, Windows was infected with a virus, that Avast detected was installed by an .exe file.

I installed Ubuntu in a dual boot, keeping my Windows data partition, that still had the virus on it. back on Ubuntu, I installed Wine, and ran a program from my data partition. When running the .exe file from Windows, it works fine. The problem is when I run the .exe file from Wine, it shows the following error:

```
The integrity of the EXE file can't be verified.
```

If I download the program from the internet, it behaves the same way. Did Wine somehow get infected with the virus? What should I do to fix this issue?

Comment: What program are you trying to run? WINE is far from being able to run programs perfectly.

Comment: internet download manager and youtube downloader

Comment: @DsSoftwareHouse Both those programs have Linux alternatives. [gWget](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/lucid/gwget/) for download manager and [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/multi-platform-youtube-dl-gui-youtube.html) for youtube downloader.

Comment: You might also be interested in using ClamAV (a linux virus scanner) to scan your data partition, and maybe remove all the infected files from it. Otherwise, whenever you move your data to a new windows computer / windows installation, you might carry the virus with you. Read [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/250290/how-do-i-scan-for-viruses-with-clamav) for more info on ClamAV

Comment: You could also try installing the latest version of Wine, see my post here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/729375/running-steam-through-wine/729377#729377

Answer (score 1):

First of all, do you know how exactly the virus got onto your pc? Did you open an email, or maybe use a crack for some program that you downloaded from the internet? Was this cracked program maybe the Internet Download Manager? If somehow the virus got executed within wine, it is very well possible that it did some harm, which will probably be only within your wine installation.

If the program that you are running is some suspicious file (e.g. if it is a crack downloaded from the internet) it is possible that this program is itself the virus you are talking about. As someone else already mentioned in the comments, there are alternatives for these programs, that don't require wine to run. For now, you should consider using those. Why did you use Internet Download Manager in the first place, does it provide any functions that other (free) download managers like JDownloader or gWget do not provide ?(I'm asking so that we can provide you with suggestions for linux alternatives that provide the same functionality)

You should also consider installing clamAV, which is a virus scanner for linux. It will allow you to scan your data partition, and remove any infected files. Otherwise, whenever you copy your data to another windows machine, you will risk infecting that machine as well! You can look into [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250290/how-do-i-scan-for-viruses-with-clamav) for more information on clamAV.

Answer (score 0):

My first impression is that wine itself is infected. Have you considered the previous comment to use a good AV scanner? If clamAV is too difficult to run try to run Panda-cloud and scan the wine manifest itself. Other applications that maybe contributing to your issue is using Libre office or some other opensource application that was infected before you installed it. Always start with a clean golive-boot CD written from another PC that was virus tested before committing it to your own OS. I would not run 3rd party scripts to setup wine even if your tempted to do so as a newbie I've often found the wine manifest to be infected with ransomware and that is an easy way to get it on your machine. Have you considered another emulator like playonlinux or Crossover to un your .exe file. These would be my first choice, if your cash strapped like most of us during covid pandemic then you could try an older release of "win4linux"